# jquery .css() mehod not working until adding or removing any character

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In order to validate html table cells, I implemented a sumbit phase control mechanism to check required fields are filled and values are valid.

This was my first solution based on my research:

```
// validate table cells
$(document).ready(function() {
    var namePattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s,.'\-\\pL]{1,600}$/;
    var telPattern = /^([+]\d{1,2})(\d{10})$/;   

    $('#platform-edit').submit(function(event) {     
        var isErrorExist = false;
        var fields = $('.validateName');
        $.each(fields, function(i, field) {

            var value = $(field).val();            
            if (value == null || value == ""){
                $(field).css('border-color', 'red');
                isErrorExist = true;
            } else{
                $(field).css('border-color', '');
                if (!namePattern.test(value)) { // Pattern to check if value is valid
                    $(field).css('color', 'red');
                    isErrorExist = true;
                } else {
                    $(field).css('color', '');
                }
            }

        });

        fields = $('.validateTel');
        $.each(fields, function(i, field) {

            var value = $(field).val();

            if (value != "" && !telPattern.test(value)) { // Pattern to check if value is valid
                $(field).css('color', 'red');
                isErrorExist = true;
            } else {
                $(field).css('color', '');
            }

        });


        if(isErrorExist){
            event.preventDefault();
        }

    });

});
```

What I wanted to do is easy. If a required field is empty change the border color, if field is not empty but the value entered is not valid against pattern, change text color. However, this is not working properly on **.validateTel** field. On debug mode, I can see `$(field).css('color', 'red');` line works and adds style to element. But color does not change until I add or remove a character.

I want to know the reason behind this issue.

All advises are much appreciated!

Comment: The CSS `color` property determines the color of the text. If there is no text, there's nothing to change the color of. Please create a [mre], with the HTML of the issue. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to make it runnable.

Comment: At the time I change the color of the text, value is not empty. If my post does not clear about the problem, I can try to add some visuals.

Answer (score 0):

This is the plan B, not the real answer. I am still wondering the solution of my first implementation.

I've just changed

`$(field).css('color', 'red');`

to

```
$(field).attr('style','color:red;');
```